# pythonの辞書やリストの clear()について

Tags: python, python3

dict_test = { 辞書定義 }
としたものを、ソースコード上で別の変数に代入したとき、代入の過程で経由した変数および元データ、全てがクリアされてしまうのですが、そういうものでしょうか？

下記例では、dict_monthに対してのみ、clearを行っていますが、dict_month1, dict_month2や、dict_month_EN, dict_month_JPまでクリアされてしまっているように見えます。

```
#元データ
    dict_month_EN = {
        'Jan':'January', 'Feb':'February', 'Mar':'March', 'Apr':'April',
        'May':'May', 'Jun':'June','Jun':'July', 'Aug':'August', 'Sep':'September',
        'Oct':'October', 'Nov':'November', 'Dec':'December'
    }
    
    dict_month_JP = {
        'Jan': '1月', 'Feb': '2月', 'Mar': '3月', 'Apr': '4月',
        'May': '5月', 'Jun': '6月', 'Jul': '7月', 'Aug': '8月',
        'Sep': '9月', 'Oct': '10月', 'Nov': '11月', 'Dec': '12月'
    }
    
    
    
    def test_main():
        dict_month2 = dict_month_JP
        dict_month1 = dict_month_JP
        dict_month = dict_month_JP
        print(dict_month_JP)
        print(dict_month2)
        print(dict_month1)
        print(dict_month)
    
        dict_month.clear()
        print('---------- After clear dict_month ptrn1----------')
        print(dict_month_JP)
        print(dict_month2)
        print(dict_month1)
        print(dict_month)
    
        print('---------- dict_month ptrn2----------')
        dict_month2 = dict_month_EN
        dict_month1 = dict_month2
        dict_month = dict_month1
        print(dict_month_EN)
        print(dict_month2)
        print(dict_month1)
        print(dict_month)
    
        dict_month.clear()
        print('---------- After clear dict_month ptrn2----------')
        print(dict_month_EN)
        print(dict_month2)
        print(dict_month1)
        print(dict_month)



＜＜＜＜＜　print文の結果　＞＞＞＞＞

---------- dict_month ptrn1----------
{'Jan': '1月', 'Feb': '2月', 'Mar': '3月', 'Apr': '4月', 'May': '5月', 'Jun': '6月', 'Jul': '7月', 'Aug': '8月', 'Sep': '9月', 'Oct': '10月', 'Nov': '11月', 'Dec': '12月'}
{'Jan': '1月', 'Feb': '2月', 'Mar': '3月', 'Apr': '4月', 'May': '5月', 'Jun': '6月', 'Jul': '7月', 'Aug': '8月', 'Sep': '9月', 'Oct': '10月', 'Nov': '11月', 'Dec': '12月'}
{'Jan': '1月', 'Feb': '2月', 'Mar': '3月', 'Apr': '4月', 'May': '5月', 'Jun': '6月', 'Jul': '7月', 'Aug': '8月', 'Sep': '9月', 'Oct': '10月', 'Nov': '11月', 'Dec': '12月'}
{'Jan': '1月', 'Feb': '2月', 'Mar': '3月', 'Apr': '4月', 'May': '5月', 'Jun': '6月', 'Jul': '7月', 'Aug': '8月', 'Sep': '9月', 'Oct': '10月', 'Nov': '11月', 'Dec': '12月'}
---------- After clear dict_month ptrn1----------
{}
{}
{}
{}
---------- dict_month ptrn2----------
{'Jan': 'January', 'Feb': 'February', 'Mar': 'March', 'Apr': 'April', 'May': 'May', 'Jun': 'July', 'Aug': 'August', 'Sep': 'September', 'Oct': 'October', 'Nov': 'November', 'Dec': 'December'}
{'Jan': 'January', 'Feb': 'February', 'Mar': 'March', 'Apr': 'April', 'May': 'May', 'Jun': 'July', 'Aug': 'August', 'Sep': 'September', 'Oct': 'October', 'Nov': 'November', 'Dec': 'December'}
{'Jan': 'January', 'Feb': 'February', 'Mar': 'March', 'Apr': 'April', 'May': 'May', 'Jun': 'July', 'Aug': 'August', 'Sep': 'September', 'Oct': 'October', 'Nov': 'November', 'Dec': 'December'}
{'Jan': 'January', 'Feb': 'February', 'Mar': 'March', 'Apr': 'April', 'May': 'May', 'Jun': 'July', 'Aug': 'August', 'Sep': 'September', 'Oct': 'October', 'Nov': 'November', 'Dec': 'December'}
---------- After clear dict_month ptrn2----------
{}
{}
{}
{}
```

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

辞書のコピーには単純な代入ではなく `copy()` メソッドを使用してください。

参考:
[Pythonの辞書(dict)をコピーする方法と注意点まとめ](https://www.headboost.jp/python-how-to-copy-dict/)

> ```
> 新しい辞書 = コピー元の辞書.copy()
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございました。解決しました。「copy() 」は使わないといけないんですね（「使った方が安全」という程度ではない）